# Hyperparameter metric in Google Cloud ML should contain the `val` prefix?

Tags: keras, google-cloud-ml, hyperparameters

When defining the hyperparameter metric for Google Cloud ML I can use `mean_squared_error`, but should I be using `val_mean_squared_error` instead if I want it to be comparing the validation set accuracy? Or does it do it on its own?

This is the sample hptuning config:

```
trainingInput:
  ...
  hyperparameters:
    goal: MINIMIZE
    hyperparameterMetricTag: ???mean_squared_error
```

And this is the fit invocation:

```
history = m.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=2048,
                         shuffle=False,
                         validation_data=(val_x, val_y),
                         verbose=verbose,
                         callbacks=callbacks)
```

Since I am passing my validation data and Keras, I am in doubt whether I should use `val_mean_squared_error`.

Comment: `val_mean_squared_error` is not a built-in metric of TF. It should work if you define your own metric that evaluates only on validation set,. Here is the instruction(https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/using-hyperparameter-tuning#add_your_hyperparameter_metric_to_the_graph_summary) to use your customized metric with hyperparameter tuning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: if you (I) want Google Cloud ML hyperparameter tuning to use the VALIDATION metric instead of the training metric while using Keras, you need to specify `val_mean_squared_error` (or `val_accuracy` etc).

If you stick to `accuracy` or `mean_squared_error` you will bias Google Cloud ML tuning process to select overfitting models. To avoid the overfitting while searching for the parameters you should either create your own metric (as mentioned in a comment) or use  the `fit` method with a validation set and us the `val` metrics.

---

I've updated the question to explicitly say I am using Keras, which automatically creates the `val_mean_squared_error`.

To get the answer I realized I could do a simple test: both with `val_mean_squared_error` and `mean_squared_error` while using Keras and invoking `fit` with the validation parameter set and compare the job results with the reported metrics.

Comment: Thanks! And you can check it by running the code in your local machine and see if there is `val_mean_squared_error` written to the final TF summaries. If there is, then it should just work on CloudML Engine.

Comment: Yes, it does. Keras automatically includes the "val_" for the loss function and each metric in the summary (and history) if you pass a validation set (or validation percentage) parameter.